# Restart pods in deployment A when deployment B changes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Stuck deploying a legacy application I don't control to k8s that requires a list of IP addresses on the command line, those IPs being the pods in deployment B, eg.:

`./legacy_app -s 10.1.0.1 10.1.0.2 10.2.0.2` - call this app deployment A

(the IP addresses are gathered by querying the `.../pods` endpoint of the k8s API during pod launch)

When deployment B changes (scales out / in, pods restart, etc), the list of IPs changes, and I need the pods in deployment A to restart, in order to re-query the API for the correct list of IPs.

How can I cleanly achieve this, ideally using standard k8s primitives?

What I've tried so far:

- an app that calls `watch` on deployment B, and on detecting a `MODIFIED` event, updates a label on deployment A, forcing a restart. This kinda works, but requires the watcher to pause for a few seconds before restarting deploy A - without the pause, the list of IPs is often not up to date by the time deploy A restarts, resulting in an incomplete list. However, the longer it pauses, the more data I'm losing. This adds a bit more operational complexity than I like.

What I'm going to try next:

- replacing pid 1 on deployment A with a monitoring loop that (re-) starts the legacy app with the new list of IPs when the list changes.
- can I update a configMap or a label on deployment A pods containing the list of IPs, and somehow use that to signal when a restart is needed?

Is there a better way? Coming into k8s I expected there to be some kind of hook / watch I could subscribe to, and run a "restart all pods in deployment" type command, but that feature doesn't appear to exist.

I'm clearly new to k8s, any input much appreciated.

k8s 1.14 on AWS EKS

Comment: refactor app B to use the **service** of app A instead of raw IPs, that way you wont have to restart anything

Comment: @EfratLevitan I think you meant refactor app A to use the service of app B, but unfortunately app A needs a list of app B's ip addresses - just pointing it the service IP won't work in app A's case, hence this whole "restart app A" setup I'm trying to achieve :(

Comment: If it can use DNS names, and you know how many to expect, then you could turn app B into a StatefulSet and its host names would be predictable (`app-b-0.app-b.nsname.svc.cluster.local`, `app-b-1....`).  (But there are some unfortunate DNS caching implementations out there, too.)

Comment: `kubectl rollout restart deployment/app-a` will work for a CLI tool; it works by changing an annotation on the pod spec in the deployment, so any automated tool that changes any annotation or label or environment variable or other setting will cause a restart too.

Comment: @DanielleM. Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @OhHiMark kinda - let me add the answer right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this using a bash entry script in front of deployment A, p much this pseudo code:

```
#!/bin/bash

get_deployment_B_ips() {
    echo $(curl https://$K8S_API/api/v1/namespaces/my_namespace/pods/ | \
           jq -r '[.items[] | select(.metadata.labels.app=="deployment-B") | select(.status.phase=="Running")] | map(.status.podIP + ":9125") |  join(" ")')
}

while true; do
CURRENT_LIST=$(get_deployment_B_ips)

  if [[ "$IP_LIST" == "$CURRENT_LIST" ]]; then
    sleep 5
  else
   # restart the process with new IP LIST
  fi
done
```

This works great for now, but going forward I'm going to read about implementation details of k8s Operators, and see if they can provide a cleaner fix than this.

Marking this as the answer to my question, unless a better solution comes along.

Comment: Was there any better solution found ? I need to rollout restart deployment-A whenever deployment-B happens.